# serial char read first letter if it is ";" print char without fists letter

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, c++

I'm working on a project and I need to print serial to a LCD but only if the first letter of the serial is ":"

I have the serial being stored in a char and a if statement reading the first letter of the char to see if it is ":" From there I can't get it to print to the LCD without the first letter. I also don't know how to clear the char.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

char inData[20];
char inChar;
byte index = 0;

void setup(){
 lcd.begin(16, 2);
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  while(Serial.available() > 0) 
  {
      if(index < 19)
      {
      inChar = Serial.read();
      inData[index] = inChar;
      index++;
      inData[index] = '\0';
  }
 if(inData[0] == ':') {
   lcd.print(inData);
   }

  }
 }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as dead. It had been answered, but not accepted and the OP has disappeared more than a year ago.

Comment: The answer to this question has been accepted. So what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell it to print starting from the second character.

```
lcd.print(inData + 1);
```

Comment: ok seams to work but when i do ":test" in serial monitor i get "ttetestest" any ideas

Comment: That's because the rest of your code is wrong.

Comment: whats wrong with it and do u know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you looked at your output yet?

Comment: what you mean? when I type ":test" the LCD says "ttetestest"

Comment: Yes, but have you actually *looked* at it?

Comment: well ya it is printing the first letter than the other letter in the char. i under stand what going on with it but dont know how to fix it. i need it to be just one work "test" not print the letters in the char in order.

Comment: Consider this question: How often are you outputting?

Comment: i did some messing around with the code and fixed it but i still need to clear the char and i dont know how.